# How to find the next numbers in the sequence related to regular polygons

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, logic

[image: regular polygons sequence image]
How can I find the next polygons, line segments(in blue) and related numbers (in red) given the sequence in this image?

---

The question asks up to 7th element, but I don't know the related number or line segment for the nth element other than the polygon will have n+2 sides, and that the number in red is equal to number of polygons "inside" the regular polygon.

---

@BrianM.Scott Suggestion
[possible 5th, 6th and 7th](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECGdE.png)

Comment: You asked an incompletely  specified question. How are the blue line segments determined?

Comment: It appears that we are to assume that each pair of vertices with exactly one vertex between them are connected by a blue segment. If you draw the next two cases, you should see that the red numbers follow a very simple pattern starting at $n=3$; the $n=1$ and $n=2$ cases do not fit this pattern.

Comment: @Somos The problem does not mention how the blue line segments are determined either. That's also why I'm finding it difficult, I don't know why it does not connect all vertices on the 4th polygon

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks I did the next couple ones according to this rule, unfortunately i don't have access to the author's answer but it seems reasonable

Comment: @Tempo: You’re welcome. I can’t be positive, but the fact that the author did not include the three diagonals of the hexagon really does suggest that he’s just connecting vertices with just one between them.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE!

draw the blue edges according to the algorithm given by Brian M. Scott,

the sequence is the number of distinct areas created inside the polygon by the interior edges!!!!

inside the triangle there are no interior edges, so there is namely only one area: $\mathbf{\color{red}{1}}$

inside the square there are $4$ triangles: $\mathbf{\color{red}{4}}$

inside the pentagon there are $10$ triangles and a central pentagon: $\color{red}{10+1=\mathbf{11}}$

inside the hexagon there are $12$ triangles and a central hexagon: $\color{red}{12+1=\mathbf{13}}$

[Euler’s formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) works for the first two graphs since they are planar.